# Exposing Zeppelin Paragraph Link with anonymous Access

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am trying to expose Apache Zeppelin Paragraph Link with anonymous Access. I am using Zeppelin 0.6.1 with LDAP authentication.

There is no straightforward way to do this, I tried exposing this URL in Shro.ini but it did not work.

I also tried making call to /ap/login in the background with credentials, but even then the link is not displaying anything.

What could be a possible solution in this scenario. I need to include the Zeppelin Paragraph Link on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that anonymous login is enabled for your zeppelin notebook, check if the following line is there in **shiro.ini** :

```
/** = anon
```

If yes, then check **zeppelin-site.xml** for the following line :

```
<property>
<name>zeppelin.anonymous.allowed</name>
<value>true</value>
<description>Anonymous user allowed by default</description>
</property>
```

Comment: In this case, security is compromised. There is a jira issue logged in zeppelin and team might provide this feature.

Comment: The OP is using LDAP so he pretty much cares about the security, this way you opening up the whole thing to anon users!